# setOnMapClickClickListener does not do anything on Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, geolocation

I wanted to put a marker on the mapView by using GoogleMap API when I click on the map and the marker should be located on where I click on the map by using the following code:

```
class MapsActivity : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    // Set the map click listener
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this)
}

override fun onMapClick(latLng: LatLng) {
    // Handle map click event
    // For example, you can add a marker at the clicked location
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker at Clicked Location"))

    // Move camera to the clicked location
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
}
```

}

But why the app does not respond or react to anything when i tap on the map after the code above has been implemented?

Thanks

Comment: Any error shown in your logs? That would be really helpful.

Comment: I tried reproducing your code on my end but everything seems to be working fine. Any details that you can add that would help debug your issue?

Comment: @Yrll oh wow, such a weird phenomenon, I still cant click the map to show the marker, I have no clue what I did wrong at this point.

Comment: Any error on your IDE? Are you using Android Studio? Also please make sure that you are importing all the needed dependencies.

Comment: Yes on Android Studio, no error on logcat, its just that the marker does not appear. Gotta check for dependencies @Yrll

Comment: Yeah, that would be your best bet as of now. Since everything works just fine on my end with the code you provided.